# what are some Django librarys useful for autocomplete?

Tags: django, autocomplete

So i have a model called partner which has a name. The name has a foreign key reference to it self. So when i create a second partner i can see the list of previous names i created. Those are potential parents. I want to either filter my parents so the user only sees the parents not all the names or i want to make a autocomplete feature that helps the user type it in.

```
class Partner(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):

    INVOICE_METHOD_CHOICE = (
        ("PAPER", "Paper"),
        ('EMAIL', 'Email'),
    )

    LEGAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICES = (
        ('CORPORATION', 'Corporation'),
        ('LLC', 'LLC'),
        ('SOLE PROPRIETOR', 'Sole Proprietor'),
        ('PARTNERSHIP', 'Partnership'),
    )

    PARTNER_OFFICE_CHOICES = (
        ('HEADQUARTERS', 'Headquarters'),
        ('DIVISION', 'Division Office'),
        ('SITE', 'Site'),
        ('DC', 'Distribution Center'),
    )

    ADDRESS_TYPES = (
        ('Billing', 'Billing'),
        ('Shipping', 'Shipping'),
        ('Physical', 'Physical'),
    )

    STATUS = Choices('Active', 'Inactive', 'Credit Hold',)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, 
    verbose_name='Account Name', )




    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        help_text="Parent Company name (if necessary)",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        max_length=200
        )
```

What are some good librarys for autocomplete in a form field? Also is there any good tutorials on how i can implement it? i tried django autocomplete but it seems like i can only get it to work on admin and not anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to tackle this is to simply write it yourself.  It's easy to do and is typically called a typeahead.

You add an event listener ('change') on the input search box.  Every time that change happens, grab what they typed, fire an AJAX call to your server, return all matching values that could apply and display them in the input as grayed out (suggestion) or a dropdown list with all the potential values.

You may find that you're pounding the database with too many calls.  For that, you may want to wait three characters for the first request or just simply wait for a few seconds after text is typed for a slowdown in typing than fire the AJAX call (similar to Amazon).